# Trigger en SQL server

Tags: sql, trigger

Quería hacer una consulta de triggers en SQL Server.
No sé si será complejo pero estoy necesitando resolver lo siguiente:

La columna CASOS Vinculados necesito que sea un campo calculado a través de la ejecución de un trigger, cada vez que un registro se inserta, se actualiza o se elimina.
No sé cómo realizarlo porque el trigger debería recorrer todos los registros de igual apellido y de igual nombre y en la columna CASOS Vinculados colocar una cadena de texto que sea igual a los números de casos en que se vincula un mismo apellido con el mismo nombre.

En la tabla que pego acá sería como debería quedar el resultado.
[image: Tabla]

Comment: Esta tabla no está normalizada siguiendo las normas: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos Lo más fácil sería crear una tabla que mantenga la relación entre casos.

Comment: Yo creo que no es un enfoque adecuado, porque tendras mucha labor para darle mantenimiento al campo "Casos vinculados" porque no obtas mejor tener una relacion maestro-detalle, siendo el detalle cada caso

Comment: Además de lo comentado arriba deberias pensar un criterio que no tenga posibilidad de ambiguedad en la busqueda de casos relacionados, que en este caso estas utilizando Nombre y Apellido, donde surge la posibilidad que si dos personas distintas con mismo nombre  y apellido tendrian todos sus casos realcionados, deberias utilizar algun campo de identificacion único por persona

Answer (score 2):

Si tu tabla base no es tan grande, no necesitas un trigger para mantener la columna, sino puedes realizar el calculo al vuelo en una consulta, que puedes también almacenar como una vista para no repetirte.

La idea básica es tirar de la cláusula [`for xml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) para concatenar en una columna todas las filas que muestran coincidencias.

Un ejemplo vale más que mil palabras:

```
with
Caso as (
          select cast('20121130' as date) FechaAlta, 17853 Caso, 'AMENDOAIN' Apellido, 'Jose Abel' Nombre
union all select '20121130', 28080, 'AMENDOAIN', 'Jose Abel'
union all select '20121130', 36035, 'Estevez', 'Francisco'
union all select '20130607', 43868, 'Estevez', 'Francisco'
union all select '20121130', 31107, 'Fernandez', 'Pablo'
union all select '20121130', 31109, 'Fernandez', 'Pablo'
union all select '20121130', 30563, 'Fernandez', 'Roberto'
union all select '20121130', 30995, 'Fernandez', 'Roberto'
union all select '20121130', 31005, 'Fernandez', 'Roberto'
union all select '20140402', 65791, 'Gutierrez', 'Isabel'
union all select '20121130', 35006, 'Jimenez', 'Omar'
union all select '20140829', 55013, 'Jimenez', 'Omar'
union all select '20160513', 74159, 'Jimenez', 'Omar'
union all select '20150605', 54386, 'Rancedo', 'Lucia'
union all select '20160914', 50973, 'Villar', 'Anahi'

)
select   *
       , stuff(
          (select ', ' + cast(caso as varchar(20)) 
            from Caso c2
           where c2.Apellido = c1.Apellido  
             and c2.Nombre = c1.Nombre
           order by Caso
             for xml path('')
          ), 1, 2, '') as CasosVinculados
  from Caso c1
```

El resultado obtenido es:

```
FechaAlta  Caso        Apellido  Nombre    CasosVinculados
---------- ----------- --------- --------- ---------------------
2012-11-30 17853       AMENDOAIN Jose Abel 17853, 28080
2012-11-30 28080       AMENDOAIN Jose Abel 17853, 28080
2012-11-30 36035       Estevez   Francisco 36035, 43868
2013-06-07 43868       Estevez   Francisco 36035, 43868
2012-11-30 31107       Fernandez Pablo     31107, 31109
2012-11-30 31109       Fernandez Pablo     31107, 31109
2012-11-30 30563       Fernandez Roberto   30563, 30995, 31005
2012-11-30 30995       Fernandez Roberto   30563, 30995, 31005
2012-11-30 31005       Fernandez Roberto   30563, 30995, 31005
2014-04-02 65791       Gutierrez Isabel    65791
2012-11-30 35006       Jimenez   Omar      35006, 55013, 74159
2014-08-29 55013       Jimenez   Omar      35006, 55013, 74159
2016-05-13 74159       Jimenez   Omar      35006, 55013, 74159
2015-06-05 54386       Rancedo   Lucia     54386
2016-09-14 50973       Villar    Anahi     50973

(15 row(s) affected)
```